# js how to convert string to utf-8

Tags: javascript, php, utf-8

I am trying to parse a csv file, but this file format is in ANSI. So when I print out the result on page, it looks like below:
[ANSI file output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a36P9.png)

and I use following code in my test php file to convert the string:

```
iconv(mb_detect_encoding($str, mb_detect_order(), true), "UTF-8", $str);
```

then it looks normal now as this:

[normal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mg9JR.png)

But I'd like to do the conversion on front side, using js, so is there any way to convert the string to utf-8 format like php method -> iconv().

Thanks.

Comment: if you can use node, look in core modules, 'string_decoder'.

Comment: ANSI using what code page, exactly? There is no such thing as just "ANSI".

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample code on reading one file using a file input control and displays the first line along with some of the file's properties:

```
<input type="file" id="fileinput" />
<script type="text/javascript">
 function readSingleFile(evt) {
 //Retrieve the first (and only!) File from the FileList object
 var f = evt.target.files[0]; 

 if (f) {
  var r = new FileReader();
  r.onload = function(e) { 
      var contents = e.target.result;
    alert( "Got the file.n" 
          +"name: " + f.name + "n"
          +"type: " + f.type + "n"
          +"size: " + f.size + " bytesn"
          + "starts with: " + contents.substr(1, contents.indexOf("n"))
      );  
    }
    r.readAsText(f);
  } else { 
    alert("Failed to load file");
  }
}

 document.getElementById('fileinput').addEventListener('change', readSingleFile, false);
</script>
```

You can use Reading Files Using The HTML5 FileReader API. It is pointless to try to convert the file after contents were ruined when trying to load in a wrong encoding.

Try looking into below articles if you want to go deep down:

[htmlgoodies](https://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=iLqARKYneo0)

[html5rocks](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/reading-files-using-the-html5-filereader-api#readastext)

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is that original file format is in ANSI, so I want to make the file format as UTF-8, or convert the read string to utf-8.